# Q. What is the most effective /testfor command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok, I've tried many variants of `/testfor`command and tried them in the lastest snapshot, 15w31c, to 1.8.6 and nothing works **AT ALL**.

The list of commands I've tried:

- `/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:iron_­sword"}]}`
- `/testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:­iron_sword"}]}`
- `/testfor @p {SelectedItemSlot:0,Inventory:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:iron_sword"}]­}`
- `/testfor @p {Inventory:[{tag:{display:{Name:"Iron_Sword"}}}]}`
- And more but I can't remember them due to the frustration

The idea I'm trying to get at is you have a special book when right-clicked it'll spawn two items. One of them you must have on the second hand, in 15w31c, at all time that will interact with whatever weapon of your choosing, *Swords, Axes, and Bow & Arrows*. The second item is just a book so no real need for it to be forced on right now. I know I have to use `/testfor` for the book, second hand item, and weapons, but like I said nothing is working.

Comment: Tried the first one, it worked....but remove the quotes from "minecraft:iron_sword"

Comment: Second one works, remove quotes, when sword in slot 1 (0b) and since 2 of 2 work, I'll stop there unless you are still having issues.

Comment: Nothing but the same thing but only this ---> My name did not match the required data structure

Comment: I had the sword in slot 1, it worked, when it wasn't I got that. That means it failed detection. Which slot are you testing?

Comment: 0 for the time being

Comment: In game slot number. Like, the keybinding number, just so there is absolutely no confusion. I take 0 to mean the slot bound to the '1' key. If so, then I got a positive match with that slot and both commands I tested.

Comment: I already knew that 0 means the 1 button.

Comment: All commands you've given work exactly as I'd expect them to. What do you mean by *"nothing is working"*?

Comment: @colorfusion I have the command block connect to a comparator to another command block testing if the first one is work and I've tested the commands ydobonebi has. Either is say it did not match the required data structure or nothing will do anything

Comment: @JordanRamirez Are you powering the first command block? Remember that this will only give an output of 1 power, so the second command block can only be 1 block away. Could you give a screenshot of your command blocks, and the inventory layout that you're expecting it to detect? The commands themself work, but they all do different things and it isn't really clear what you want them to do.

Comment: [link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cnvnt/19700955243/in/dateposted-public/)

Answer (score 1):

Tested the first 2 commands. Removing the quotes from `minecraft:iron_sword`  and places a space after `@p` produces expected results.

[[image]`/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:ironsword}]}`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzXep.png)

---

[[image]`/testfor @p {Inventory:[{slot:0b,id:minecraft:iron_sword}]}`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CFuI.png)

---

[[image]Same as above, but sword in wrong slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv62A.png)

---

In the first two examples, if you had those in a command block with a comparator attached, the comparator would output a 1 redstone strength. The last example would not output any redstone strength.

Comment: Yes, I blurred out my gamer tag...sorry I don't want people to know it on here :)

Comment: Don't even need to remove the quotation marks; the commands OP gave should be working.

Comment: @colorfusion I agree you shouldn't have to, but I got different results each way. I can't explain why.

Comment: Worked fine for me with and without the quotes. Makes it easier to read IMO (and will work with tools that use stricter JSON parsing), but it's mainly a matter of preference.

Comment: @colorfusion well, opinion is opinion, for me it takes up more characters (and there is a limit) and it's less readable to me. It breaks the continuity of the context to which it's being applied and makes it seem disjunctive. But hey, you know what they say about opinions? Just like assholes, everybody has one.

Comment: and both ways should work with strick JSON parsing btw

Comment: [Strict JSON parsing requires quotes around strings](http://i.imgur.com/jwjxyV8.png). That said though, other parts of OP's command also fail with non-lenient parsing. Just noting that removing the quotes isn't necessary to make it work.